# Rav Moshe on mechitzah and kalus rosh

Tags: sources-mekorot, wedding, moshe-feinstein, mechitza-partition

I read somewhere in the *Igros Moshe* that a *mechitzah* is required at every wedding. Does anyone know where in the *Igros Moshe* it says that the reason we have a *mechitzah* at a wedding is to prevent *kalus rosh*?

Comment: Why the downvote? Regular [tag:sources-mekorot] question.

Comment: I don't know (hence this isn't an answer), but in [_Orach Chayim_ volume 1 number 41](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14673&pgnum=102) he seems to be saying he tends to think no _m'chitza_ is needed at weddings. (A tip of my hat to https://web.archive.org/web/20110728082803/http://www.chabadtalk.com/go/ph/ph-10.htm for pointing me to that _t'shuva_.)

Comment: Note that the Kitzur Shulcahn Aruch in 149:1 says that "if men and women ate in the same room, then one cannot say שהשמחה במעונו at a wedding, as there is no [Jewish] Simcha when the yetzer hara is aroused."

Comment: @Shokhet No, he's asking for something other than what he supposedly read

Comment: In responsum #41, as well as in #39 earlier, R' Moshe indicates that *m'chitzos* are required to avoid *kalus rosh* where there are large and necessary gatherings of men and women. In responsum #41, he indicates that weddings are likely different (based on an inference from *P'sachim* 86b). It seems the rationale is that crowds are not halachically required to gather at weddings as they are for prayer at a *shul*. Further, if the reason to prevent *kalus rosh* is due to מורא מקדש (which applies e.g. to prayer and Torah study in a *shul*), that would not apply at a wedding.

Comment: I may be wrong, though I believe R' Moshe attended many wedding dinners without a mechitza. Did his own children's weddings all have one?

Answer (score 2):

While there are no clear Teshuvos on the matter, R' Lawrence (Levi) Reisman wrote a letter into the Jewsh Press where he noted that:

> ..two of the four weddings Reb Moshe made had completely separate seating. At Reb Reuven’s wedding, there were some mixed tables to accommodate those from his wife’s side who wouldn’t sit any other way..
>
> ..It would appear that Reb Moshe preferred separate seating, but was ready to accommodate those who felt otherwise..

See [here](http://www.torahmusings.com/2005/09/mixed-seating-at-weddings_22/) for a longer excerpt.

Comment: I heard a story that a well-known anonymous Rav attended a mixed-seating wedding. He ate a rich chocolate cake for desert and asked the waiter for a 2nd. His wife, sitting next to him, nudged him saying, "Do you REALLY need to eat that?" To which the rav replied, "That's It! From now on, separate seating at weddings!" Hence, the minhag began :-)

Answer (score -2):

[Igros Moshe Orach Chaim 1:39](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=97)

[Igros Moshe Orach Chaim 3:23](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=919&st=&pgnum=315)

Comment: Neither link seems to discuss weddings

Comment: If neither of those links discuss weddings, what halachic source does mention that one is required to have mechitzah at a wedding to prevent kalus rosh? (i.e. mishnah berurah, kitzur shulchan aruch and shulchan aruch etc.)